# Bitwise concatenation in C

Tags: c, binary, printf, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to concatenate two binary numbers in C. So if I have `1010` and `0011` I want my result to be `10100011`. I wrote a short routine that I thought would do the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int first = 1010;
    int second = 0011;
    int result = (first << 4) | second;
    printf("%d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that the printed number of course is going to be in decimal, but I figured that after my bitwise operations I'd be getting the decimal equivalent of `10100011`, or 163. However, my result is printed as 16169. So I guess my question is...what part of this am I not understanding here? Is it just a misunderstanding of how printf is working, or are my bitwise operations incorrect? Is it a problem to try to do this with `int`s?

Comment: `1010` is the decimal representation of binary number `1111110010`. And `0011` is actually a base 8 literal meaning decimal 9.

Comment: and what made you think that the `int` _representation_ will be binary instead of decimal?

Comment: 16169 happens, because of that int data type is of 4 bytes long, not 1 byte.\

Answer (score 15):

You forgot the prefix `0b`, so this should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int first = 0b1010;
              //^^v See here
    int second = 0b0011;
    int result = (first << 4) | second;
    printf("%d", result);

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
163
```

In your examle the 'binary numbers' aren't binary numbers. The first one is a normal decimal number (`1010`) and the second one is a octal number, because of the prefix `0` so in decimal the second number was: `9`

So what happened is:

```
1010 -> decimal
0011 -> octal
```

First number:

```
     11 1111 0010      
----------------- << 4
11 1111 0010 0000
```

Second number (->decimal->binary):

```
  octal    decimal       binary
  0011  ->    9     ->  0000 1001
```

And your calculation:

```
11 1111 0010 0000   first number
             1001   second number
----------------- |
11 1111 0010 1001 = 16169
```

Comment: Is that standard, or a compiler extension? I know it's recently become standard in C++, but I am not as familiar with C.

Comment: @juanchopanza as far as i know it's from GNU and i think C standard doesn't define it, but maybe it has changed

Comment: Really, C++14 standard added binary literal.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to be dependent on the new standard, you can learn a simple rule overextension binary system in hexadecimal

```html
HEX  BIN
 00  0000
 01  0001
 02  0010
 03  0011
 04  0100
 05  0101
 06  0110
 07  0111
 08  1000
 09  1001
 0A  1010
 0B  1011
 0C  1100
 0D  1101
 0E  1110
 0F  1111
 10 10000
```

So you program may be rewritten as:

```html
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int first = 0xA;  // 1010;
    int second = 0x3; // 0011;
    int result = (first << 4) | second;
    printf("%X", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you also return (0xA<<4) + 0x3.

In other words

1010 0000 + 0000 0011 = 1010 0011

Answer (score 0):

use strings and concatenate those. they values are being read as integers so (int << 0x4) isn't shifting 4 spaces left it is multiplying by 16. fast base 10 to base 2

```
int b10tob2(int num) {
    int bin = 0, k = 1;

    while (num) {
        bin += (num % 2) * k;
        k *= 10;
        num /= 2;
    }

    return bin;
}
```

Comment: Out-of-the-Box idea. I think it was more understandable if the name was more elaborate. (Somebody already seems to have tried to fix the code block. May take a while if you don't take it into your own hands.)