# Append bits to beginning and end of 10-bit integer

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

The SPI device I'm using needs 4 bits appended to the left of a 10-bit value, and 2-bits appended to the right.

For example, suppose you have a 10-bit value:

```
0110100110 - or 422
```

We want to add `0110` to the left side, and `00` to the right side.

So the result would be:

```
0110011010011000
```

How would I do this?

Comment: In what language? Are the appended bits always the same?

Comment: C, and yes.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitwise concatenation in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180015/bitwise-concatenation-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this would be to shift the bits to their desired positions and use the OR operator ( | ) to combine the bits.

```
int num = 0b0110100110;    
int left_bits = 0b0110;
int right_bits = 0b00;

int result = (left_bits << 12) | (num << 2) | right_bits
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I've found what seems to be a good solution.

As the appended bits are always the same value, and in the same position, I declare an int of 6000.

I then shift the 10-bit value to the left by 2, and or the two together.

```
int x = 0x6000;
int y = 0xDB << 2;

int result = x ^ y;
```

Comment: `^` is XOR, not OR. You should use `|` instead

Comment: You're right, but in this case I don't think it makes any difference.

Comment: The definition of 'int' changes from platform to platform, and its also signed so if the four leading bits started with a 1 it would be interpreted as a negative number on a 16 bit system. To be safe and portable use 'uint16_t' rather than 'int'