# How to concatenate binary macro values? What is the binary type?

Tags: c++, binary, concatenation, arduino-c++

Working on an arduino project that uses binary command codes.

Sample Rate and Filter Type are 2 codes that are concatenated. 
Sample Rate= MSB half and Filter Type = LSB half.

found: [Bitwise concatenation in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180015/bitwise-concatenation-in-c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    int first = 0b1010;
              //^^v See here
    int second = 0b0011;
    int result = (first << 4) | second;
    printf("%d", result);

    return 0;
```

Which shows how to concatenate two binary values and add them.

Have all the binary codes in the `.h file` as macros.
Can I do the same for pure binary values? What is the type? 
Will use the concatenated binary value - as a command in a function.

[Usage of binary code command currently Looks Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GJEP.png)

All the Macros:

```
    //Sample Rate and Filter Type Codes From ADS1261 Datasheets
/*Binary Code Commands Defining Sampling Rate and Filter Type - http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1261.pdf#page=61*/

 //ADC DATA RATE
#define SPS_2_PT_5        0b00000  //SPS = 2.5
#define SPS_5             0b00001  //SPS = 5
#define SPS_10            0b00010  //SPS = 10
#define SPS_16_PT_6       0b00011  //SPS = 16.6
#define SPS_20_DEFAULT    0b00100  //SPS = 20 <--- this is also the default.
#define SPS_50            0b00101  //SPS = 50
#define SPS_60            0b00110  //SPS = 60
#define SPS_100           0b00111  //SPS = 100
#define SPS_400           0b01000  //SPS = 400
#define SPS_1200          0b01001  //SPS = 1200
#define SPS_2400          0b01010  //SPS = 2400
#define SPS_4800          0b01011  //SPS = 4800
#define SPS_7200          0b01100  //SPS = 7200
#define SPS_14400         0b01101  //SPS = 14400
#define SPS_19200         0b01110  //SPS = 19200
#define SPS_25600         0b00110  //SPS = 25600
#define SPS_40000         0b10000  //SPS (f_CLK - 10.24 MHz)

//Define Filter Types
#define F_SINC1 0b000 //SINC1
#define F_SINC2 0b001 //SINC2
#define F_SINC3 0b010 //SINC3
#define F_SINC4 0b011 //SINC4
#define F_FIR   0b100 //FIR// Default if not specified.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] (of *your* code).

Comment: Avoid macros as much as possible, especially when you are coding in C++ where there are better ways to do such stuff.

Comment: @MarekR what a moot comment. It is absolutely clear that macros are coming from external source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be exactly the same code. Macros would be substitute with binary literals, literals would be promoted to integers, and then left shift followed by or operators will be called.

Comment: AFAIK Arduino Uno has 16 bit int.

Comment: Using an AdaFruit "Arduino" nRF52832